# Branch cut of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, radicals, branch-cuts

I was reading something that defined the function $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$ where the branch cut is such that the argument of $z$ and $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ are in the same quadrant. I think I understand what this means and I think it corresponds to the usual branch of the square root.

Later, they say that $\sqrt{z^2-1}\leq 0$ for $z< -1$. I don't understand why this should be true. I have tried taking limits from above and below the imaginary axis but confused myself.

This is the way I'm understanding it: taking a point in the second quadrant slightly above the real axis, we can write 
$z=re^{i(\pi-\epsilon)}$ for $r>1$. Then $z^2=r^2e^{i2\pi-2\epsilon}$, i.e a complex number with argument almost $2\pi$. When you subtract one, you decrease the argument but for $\epsilon$ small it should still be nearly $2\pi$. There are two complex numbers which square to this one, one is just above the negative real axis, the other is just below the positive real axis.

To have a continuous function, we must choose the first.

Comment: What do you mean by these inequalities with complex numbers?

Comment: Well, then it clearly isn't true, as, no matter how you cut it, $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ should coincide with the usual square root when the argument is positive (which it does for your cutting along $[-1;1]$), meaning, $\sqrt{(-2)^2-1}=\sqrt{3}>0$. I assume there is a confusion somewhere.

Comment: Could you please tell me where are you reading this from?

Comment: Choose branch cuts from $-1$ to $infty$ and from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Those cuts overlap from $1$ to $\infty$.  And on the overlapped part, $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is continuous.  That leaves the segment $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Now with those cuts, you'll find that $\arg(z)$ and $arg(\sqrt{z^2-1}$ lie in the same quadrant.

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289277/analytic-functions-branch helps.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you Gerry, I think I need a branch cut bootcamp of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$, with the branch cut on  $[-1,1]$ such that $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(\sqrt{z^2-1})$ are in the same quadrant.

Branch points of $f(z)$ are at $z=-1$ and $z=1$.  Corresponding branch cuts are contours that begin at $z=-1$ and $z=1$ and end at the point at infinity.

---

> Example branch cuts include rays on the real axis from $(i)$ $z=-1$ to $z=-\infty$ and $z=1$ to $-\infty$, $(ii)$ $z=-1$ to $z=-\infty$ and $z=1$ to $\infty$, and (iii) $(i)$ $z=-1$ to $z=\infty$ and $z=1$ to $\infty$.
>
> But the branch cuts need not be straight line paths.  For example, we could choose the branch cut from $z=1$ to be hyperbolic path $\text{Im}(z)=\frac1{\text{Re}(z)}-1$ from $z=1$ to $z=i\infty$ in the first quadrant.

---

In terms of set equivalence ([See this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253239/choosing-a-branch-of-the-square-root-so-that-this-rewriting-works/2253403#2253403) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251769/what-isare-the-values-of-sqrti-sqrt-i/2251786#2251786) for references), we can write for any value of $f(z)$ as

$$\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}$$

for some value of $\sqrt{z-1}$ and some value of $\sqrt{z+1}$.  We choose, therefore, to cut the plane from $-1$ to $\infty$ and from $1$ to $\infty$, both along the real axis, so that

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{z^2-1}&=\sqrt{|z+1|}e^{i\arg(z+1)/2}\sqrt{|z-1|}e^{i\arg(z-1)/2}\\\\
&=\sqrt{|z^2-1|}e^{i(\arg(z+1)+\arg(z-1))/2}
\end{align}$$

where $0<\arg(z+1)\le 2\pi$ and $0<\arg(z-1)\le 2\pi$.  Then, $0<\arg(\sqrt{z^2-1})\le 2\pi$,

Note with these choices of branches for $\sqrt{z+1}$ and $\sqrt{z-1}$, we satisfy the requirement that $\arg(z)$ and $f(z)=\arg(\sqrt{z^2-1})$ are in the same quadrant.

Moreover, along the real axis for which $\text{Re}(z)>1$, $f(z)$ is continuous.  Hence, we have now defined a function $f(z)$ that is single-valued on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ and $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(f(z))$ are in the same quadrant.

---

Finally, note that the $\text{Re}(z)<-1$, we have $\arg(z+1)=\arg(z-1)=\pi$, $\arg(f(z))=\pi$, and $\sqrt{z^2-1}=-\sqrt{|z^2-1|}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is almost completely clear to me. Just a couple of questions: when you split the square root and say "as set equivalence," can you add a word or two? I am always afraid to do this with complex fractional powers. I think I know what you mean but want to make sure.

Comment: And this is definitely pedantic, but formally should it be strict inequalities $0<\arg(z+1)<2\pi$ and same for $\arg(z-1)$ since a priori we exclude these halflines

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I've added links to a couple of references to the idea of set equivalence in the context of the complex logarithm.

Comment: We need the non-strict inequality to define $\arg(z)$ on the entire plane.

Comment: Thank you for the links, that is now clear. I just thought that choosing an argument is equivalent to choosing a branch of the log, so that we must exclude a ray from the origin, which here would be the positive real axis, which leads to the exclusion of $[-1,\infty)$ from z-1 and $[1,\infty)$ from $z+1$.

Comment: You're really quite welcome.  I enjoyed helping you.  And I understand how all of this can be confusing at times.

Comment: @MarkViola   **such that $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(\sqrt{z^2-1})$ are in the same quadrant** . What is your motive to write this . please explain.

Comment: @MeetPatel I suggest that you read the very first sentence in the posted question.